# cocos2d-android: releasing EGL surface because paused

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android, glsurfaceview

I am new to cocos2d-android. When I pause my game it works but then when I try to resume it does not work. LogCat shows: releasing EGL surface because paused tid=9.
How to fix it? Please any reply.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are not stopping/ending the Director inside your onStop() method ?